# How to use transaction and select together, with sql2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, transactions

we have a ASP.NET site with a SQL2008 DB.

I'm trying to implement transactions in our current system.

We have a method that is inserting a new row to a table (Table_A), and it works fine with transaction. If an exception is throwed, it will do the rollback.

My problem is, that another user can't do anything that invole with Table_A in the same time - probably because it's locked.

I can understand why the transaction have to lock the new row, but I don't want it to lock the whole table - forcing user_B to wait for user_A to finish.

I have tryed to set isolationlevel ReadUncommitted and Serializable on the transaction, but it didn't work.

So i'm wondering if I also need to rewrite all my select methods, so they are able to select all the rows except the new row there is in the making?

Example:

- Table T has 10 rows(records?)
- User A is inserting a new row into table T. This take some time.
- At the same time, User B want to select the 10 rows, and dosn't care about the new row.

So I guess I somehow need to rewrite user B's select query from a "select all query" to a "select all rows that isnt bind to a transaction query". :)

Any tips is much appriciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make changes to your selects, not to the transaction that is doing the insert.

You can

- set isolation level read uncommitted for the connection doing the select, or
- specify the [WITH (NOLOCK)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx) hint against the table that is being locked, or
- specify the [WITH (READPAST)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx) hint against the table being locked

As I say, all 3 of these options are things that you'd apply to the SELECT, not the INSERT.

A final option may be to enable [SNAPSHOT isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb(VS.80).aspx), and change the database default to use that instead (There are probably many warnings I should include here, if the application hasn't been built/tested with snapshot isolation turned on)

Comment: It look like all I needed was to add "WITH(NOLOCK)" to my select query. I'll test some more and accept later.

Comment: Adding "WITH(NOLOCK)" didn't do the trick completely. Now user B select all (11) rows, and not the decired 10 rows.

Comment: So use READPAST (third option above) instead - it skips the locked rows rather than reading them

Comment: "WITH(READPAST)" works fine it seems, ty. I was testing nolock wrong with difference combos so i never came to readpast. So do you also by any chance know if I can in some way set that hint using LINQ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you need is to set your isolation level to [Read Committed Snapshot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188277.aspx).

Although it needs more space for the tempdb it is great when you don't want your selects to lock the tables.

Beware of posible [problems](http://coderjournal.com/2008/08/deadlocked-read-committed-snapshot-explained/) when using this isolation level.